proof of the properties of the whitening transformation
I am looking for a proof that the covariance matrix of a dataset is indeed the unit matrix after the transformation - I could not derive it myself.
Every article I skimmed just had a rough outline like this one for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation
Thanks!
